# Why does gunicorn in vagrant need nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, vagrant, gunicorn

Getting started on a new project and decided to try out python as my back-end rest-service using Flask and Flask-RESTful. I got everything in the box working. I can start the app with Gunicorn and curl it locally.

When I attempt to connect from a browser or ARC (a chrome app for testing rest services) or another vagrant box running an mvc client on the network the connection is refused.

I have found a way to do this that I understand with nginx as a reverse proxy on the python rest server but I do not understand what that is needed for. It seems like that would be the job of Gunicorn or am I missing something?

My vagrant file is setup like this

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.define "rest" do |rest|
        rest.vm.box = "gbarbieru/xenial"
        #rest.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
    end
    config.vm.define "mvc" do |mvc|
        mvc.vm.box = "gbarbieru/xenial"
    end

    # Disable automatic box update checking.
    # config.vm.box_check_update = false

    # Forward ports
    # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000

    # host-only access to the machine using a specific IP.
    # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

    # Public network which makes the machine appear as another 
    # physical device on your network.
    config.vm.network "public_network"

    # Share an additional folder to the guest VM.
    # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"
end
```

The flask app is literally the example from http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html.

The MVC client is not up yet I just attempted to curl from it.

Right now on my local I have 192.168.1.12 as the rest and 192.168.1.13 as the mvc and can ping all ways guest/host host/guest and guest/guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're taking the minimalistic example from your link http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html, you should make the following change on the `app.run` call : `app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', debug=True)`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

This will make sure the server is bound to all network interfaces and can be reached not only from the localhost server but also from your host in case of vagrant

The second option is to force the server to run on specific host as mentioned at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#a-minimal-application under the *Externally Visible Server* chapter

> If you run the server you will notice that the server is only
>   accessible from your own computer, not from any other in the network.
>   This is the default because in debugging mode a user of the
>   application can execute arbitrary Python code on your computer.
>
> If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network,
>   you can make the server publicly available simply by adding
>   `--host=0.0.0.0` to the command line:
>
> `flask run --host=0.0.0.0`
>
> This tells your operating system to listen on
>   all public IPs.

Comment: Thanks I actually stumbled upon that for Guincorn shortly after posting this. Just curious is there an advantage to either 0.0.0.0 or running a reverse proxy>

Comment: the main advantage to run on `0.0.0.0` is mainly that you do not need to setup the reverse proxy; so in dev mode when I need to develop the features and quickly set, I go to the simplest setup and if I can avoid the setup of additional infrastructure its much better

Comment: Last point to clarify. So when it's time to move to production is it better to go with a reverse proxy?

Comment: It depends but generally you would set a webserver or proxy to handle http request and forward when necessary to flask

Comment: Isn't that what Gunicorn is? I am used to Apache and being able to hit the address of the virtual machine so please forgive any ignorance.

Comment: well - honestly at this stage I would have said I am not much experienced myself in python dev. I am java dev but I know about the original issue `0.0.0.0` on vagrant. Maybe you can have another question for the Gunicorn part and use in Production, it will reach a broader audience

Comment: Just to note this binding to `0.0.0.0` is what Apache does by default and is not the default in this case because the debugger can allow for arbitrary Python code to be executed on the machine by any device connected to the network.